# ggplot with overlay - name the overlay with additional labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with labels on the y axis for the groups within the area plot. I added an overlay and want to name these.

Reproducible data at the bottom. For context I'm showing website session data and want to overlay when TV Campaigns are running.

Here's my ggplot and what it looks like. Below that is the commands to generate random data that I am using.

```
timeline <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions,fill = Channel, group = Channel)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 2), fun.y = sum, geom = 'line', size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_rect(data = tv_overlay, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            aes(xmin = start, xmax = end,
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
            fill = "black", alpha = 0.1)
```

This produces the following plot. Note the rectangle overlays which are meant to denote a TV campaign. How can I add a label to say "TV Campaign" to these:
[image]

### Reproducible data which will allow the above commands for timeline <- to run

```
# dimensions
channels <- c("Facebook", "Youtube", "SEM", "Organic", "Direct", "Email")
last_month <- Sys.Date() %m+% months(-1) %>% floor_date("month")
mts <- seq(from = last_month %m+% months(-23), to = last_month, by = "1 month")
yr_month <- format(mts, "%b-%Y")
dimvars <- expand.grid(Month = yr_month, Channel = channels)

# metrics
rws <- nrow(dimvars)
set.seed(42)

# generates variablility in the random data
randwalk <- function(initial_val, ...){
  initial_val + cumsum(rnorm(...))
}

Sessions <- ceiling(randwalk(3000, n = rws, mean = 8, sd = 1500)) %>% abs()
Transactions <- ceiling(randwalk(200, n = rws, mean = 0, sd = 75)) %>% abs()
Revenue <- ceiling(randwalk(10000, n = rws, mean = 0, sd = 3500)) %>% abs()

# make primary df
dataset <- cbind(dimvars, Sessions, Transactions, Revenue)

# make TV and Mass df for overlays
tv_begin <- sample(mts, 4)
tv_end <- tv_begin %m+% months(1)
tv_overlay <- data.frame(start = format(tv_begin, "%b-%Y"), end = format(tv_end, "%b-%Y"))
```

Comment: I was thinking of adding a label above "Channel" on the right but am open to suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I adjusted the code above to this: ``aes(xmin = start, xmax = end,
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                alpha = "TV Campaign")``
Is that what you meant? It never produced anything new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map `alpha` to a character values to get an extra legend entry:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions,fill = Channel, group = Channel)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = 2), fun.y = sum, geom = 'line', size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = "TV Campaign"),
            tv_overlay, inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = "black") +
  scale_alpha_manual(name = '', values = c("TV Campaign" = 0.1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: You legend! Pun intended. Thanks a lot